# Poor man's Navier-Stokes and the tent map

Tags: measure-theory, trigonometry

I'm reading the book "Turbulence: The Legacy of A. N. Kolmogorov" by Uriel Frisch, and on chapter 3 he introduces the poor man's Navier-Stokes:
$${v_{t + 1}} = 1 - 2v_t^2$$

And says that with the change of variables:
$${v_t} = \sin \left( {\pi {x_t} - \frac{\pi }{2}} \right)$$
$${v_{t + 1}} = \sin \left( {\pi {x_{t + 1}} - \frac{\pi }{2}} \right)$$
You get the following:
$${x_{t + 1}} = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{2{x_t}}\\
{2 - 2{x_t}}
\end{array}\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
,\\
,
\end{array}\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{0 \le {x_t} \le \frac{1}{2}}\\
{\frac{1}{2} \le {x_t} \le 1}
\end{array}} \right.$$

I tried to derive the steps myself (it should be elementary), but I'm not sure how to proceed after:
$\sin \left( {\pi {x_{t + 1}} - \frac{\pi }{2}} \right) = 1 - 2{\sin ^2}\left( {\pi {x_t} - \frac{\pi }{2}} \right)$.

Can someone show how these changes of variables lead to the above tent map?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: As given in [List of trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities),

$$\cos(2\theta) = 1 - 2\sin^2(\theta) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

$$\cos(\theta) = \sin(\theta + \frac{\pi}{2}) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

To get the second part (I'm not sure why the author has $2$ parts, but my best guess is this is to have $0 \le x_i \le 1$ for all $i$), you can use

$$\sin(\theta) = -\sin(\theta - \pi) \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Comment: Thank you!! That makes sense, but can you give a hint of why the solution has two different regimes for x? below 0.5 and above?

Comment: @ValientProcess You're welcome. As for why there's two different regimes for $x$, I'm not completely sure. However, I guess it could be because the author wanted the $x_i$ values to be bounded, i.e., $0 \le x_i \le 1$. To do that, they used that $\sin(\theta) = -\sin(\theta - \pi)$ to get the second one using $\pi x_{t+1} - \frac{\pi}{2} = -(2\pi x_{t} - \frac{3\pi}{2}) \implies x_{t+1} = 2 - 2x_t$. I've also added to my answer to address this issue.